# Change subsubsection to medium series

Tags: sectioning, formatting, lyx

I am using Lyx on Windows.  How do I get the formatting of the whole document to look like:

```
\subsubsection{\textmd{Blah blah blah}}
```

without manually setting it for each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only change the text:

```
\let\OriginalSubsubsection\subsubsection%
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{\OriginalSubsubsection{\textmd{#1}}}%
```

As per Stefan's suggestion if you also want to also adjust the numbering:

```
\let\OriginalTheSubsubsection\thesubsubsection
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\textmd{\OriginalTheSubsubsection}}
```

Comment: No, it does not seem to change it for me.  I am new to lyx/tex, I just put it in to the preamble, is this correct?

Comment: If you add it in your preamble, it should change the formatting of the sub-subsection to `\mdseries` (via `\textmd{...}`), but the numbering will still remain and be typeset using `\bfseries`. That is, in **bold**. Is this what you want?

Comment: CORRECTION- This does work, I was not seeing the change inside Lyx, but when I viewed as PDF it displayed correctly.  Thank you.

Comment: @Peter: Perhaps add `\let\OriginalTheSubsubsection\thesubsubsection` `\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\textmd{\OriginalTheSubsubsection}}`, this would also adjust the number. Of course for the complete text, but this might be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) to format any sectional command. For example, obtaining a medium formatting for `\subsubsection` use

```
\usepackage{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
...
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\mdseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}%
```

In a more general setting, the respective arguments of `\titleformat` is

```
\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
```

Note that optional arguments are specified using `[...]`, while mandatory arguments use `{...}`. Consequently, in the above redefinition of `\subsubsection`, `<format>=\mdseries` for medium font, `<label>=\thesubsubsection` to print the number of the sub-subsection, `<sep>=1em` to provide a space of `1`em`between the``sub-subsection title, and`` is also empty. Play around with these settings to see what fits you, or leave a comment.

Finally, read the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) for more information on the details of each component.

Comment: Thanks you for the help, however your first example removed the subsubsection numbers from the document, which is not what I am looking for. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Good explanation! In contrast to the [subsubsection patch](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25660/change-subsubsection-to-medium-series/25661#25661), the number matches the title, i.e. is not bold. And using `titlesec` further customizations would be easy.